# Why I am getting bad result for the hypertuning parameters

Tags: regression, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameter

I am trying to learn machine learning with 3 very common datasets (`Boston Housing Price`, `Red Wine Quality`, and `Bike`). I am using 3 ML models (`LinReg`, `Lasso`, and `Ridge`). The LinReg is the default of the Scikit-learn but for Lasso and Ridge, I am doing the hyper tuning.

I have 3 accuracy metrics (MAE, MSE, R2). The overall accuracy is given below

```
Dataset     Model       MAE         MSE         R2
House       LinReg      2.96        19.60       0.74
House       Lasso       4.58        47.44       0.39
House       Ridge       5.39        65.25       0.16
```

```
Dataset     Model       MAE         MSE         R2
Wine        LinReg      0.50        0.42        0.35
Wine        Lasso       0.68        0.65        -0.0008   
Wine        Ridge       0.66        0.62        0.05
```

```
Dataset     Model       MAE         MSE             R2
Bike        LinReg      106.56      20812.63        0.37
Bike        Lasso       118.21      25732.92        0.23
Bike        Ridge       136.31      31186.12        0.07
```

You can see, the `MAE` and `MSE` are always high for the `Lasso` and `Ridge` than the `LinReg`.  Even, I am getting `negative R2` for the Wine dataset and Lasso model.

I did very basic data pre-processing and mostly not any feature engineering. As they are very basic datasets.

I am using `Optuna` for hypertuning. At the time of hypertuning, I am doing `5 fold cross-validation`, `neg_mean_squared_error` as scoring function and set `direction="minimize"`.

For the `Lasso` and `Ridge` T am tuning only `alpha` and the ranges in between `1e-7, 1e2`.

```
def lasso_objective(X_train, y_train, kfolds) -> Callable[[Trial], float]:
    def objective(trial: Trial) -> float:
        args: Dict = dict(
            alpha=trial.suggest_float("alpha", 1e-7, 1e2), 
        )
        estimator = Lasso(**args)
        scores = cross_validate(
            estimator, X=X_train, y=y_train, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=cv_method, n_jobs=-1
        )
        return float(np.mean(scores["test_score"]))

    return objective
```

```
def tune(objective):
    study = optuna.create_study(direction="minimize")
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=200)
    params = study.best_params
    best_score = study.best_value
    return params
```

I am supposed to get better results for the `Lasso` and `Ridge` (as I am doing tuning here). Could you tell me why I am getting bad `MAE` and `MSE` for them? What should I do to get better results for them?

Comment: Lasso, ridge and linear regression are all linear models. Is the outcome of interest a linear function of the features? See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/437563/poor-performance-on-regularized-models

Comment: Yes, they are. But I should get at least better result for Lasso and Ridge that LinReg (because of the hypertuning)

Comment: See [3.2 Tuning the Hyper-parameters of an estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html).

Comment: And also see [Hyper-parameter optimizers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#hyper-parameter-optimizers).

Comment: @Opps_0 Are you re-scaling `X_train` to be expressed in common units?

Comment: @Sycorax, No. I am not doing any scaling. Should I do `StandardScaler()`?

Comment: Scaling the data is recommended for penalized regression models. Does this phenomenon still manifest if you scale the data?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have to check. But, I am thinking I have more models (LinReg, Lasso, Ridge, Knn, RF, and SVR). So, if I apply scaling, does this will affect other models? I have to scale both `X_train` and `X_test`, right? Moreover, I was thinking about the `Outliers`.

Comment: These are all valid questions, but they are somewhat unrelated to the question stated in your original post, so it's best to pose them in their own threads. Before you do, though, take a moment to review the archived questions by using a [Search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=).

Comment: @Sycorax I checked with the scaled data. Yes, they are showing the same result (getting a better score for the default models than the tuned ones). I have edited the questions with the tuned params ranges if you can give any idea!

Comment: Wait, you're *minimizing* the *negative* square error? Don't you want to *minimize* the square error?

Comment: As I know, if I you want to tune the models, or cross_validate using the utilities present in Scikit, I have to  use `neg_mean_squared_error`

Comment: The documentation says that scorer objects follow the convention that the higher score is better https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values whence we have `neg_mean_squared_error`. You want to **minimize** the error, not maximize it.

Comment: If we minimise `neg_mean_squared_error` that will maximize the `mean_squared_error`

Comment: ....and your complaint is that MSE is too high...?

Comment: Oops Sorry, If we minimise `neg_mean_squared_error` that will minimize the `mean_squared_error` as per this blog (https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-model-selection-and-hyperparameter-tuning-736158357dc4)

Comment: Draw a the function $y=x^2$ and identify the minimum. Then draw the function $y = - (x^2)$ and identify the minima. Are they the same?

Comment: Nope, they must not the same. Then, your suggestion is to use `maximize`?

Comment: or `mean_square_error` with `minimize`.

Comment: If you want `mean_square_error` then you have to use `neg_mean_square_error` in the cross validate. Then the code is fine, I think!

Comment: Why do you want to maximize **error**?

Comment: Here `neg_mean_square_error` is actually giving us `mean_square_error`. Our aim is to minimize the `mean_square_error`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR -- The code in the question **maximizes** model misfit because it uses `"minimize"` in conjunction with `neg_mean_squared_error`. The correct usage is `"maximize"` in conjunction with `"neg_mean_squared_error"`. We know this because the `sklearn` documentation says so, and also because we can demonstrate it with a simple script.

In every machine learning problem, the task is to minimize the error. One way to measure error in regression is to take the square of the difference between the observed data and the model's predictions, i.e. minimizing $(y - \hat{y})^2$.

On the other hand, the package `sklearn` adopted the convention of *maximizing* a "score". In `skelarn`'s parlance, a "score" is an objective function that you want to maximize. From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter):

> For the most common use cases, you can designate a scorer object with the scoring parameter; the table below shows all possible values. **All scorer objects follow the convention that higher return values are better than lower return values.** Thus metrics which measure the distance between the model and the data, like `metrics.mean_squared_error`, are available as `neg_mean_squared_error` which return the negated value of the metric.

We can verify that `sklearn` works as described in the documentation with a simple script.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)

lasso = Lasso(random_state=0, max_iter=10000)

foo = cross_validate(lasso, X=X,y=y,scoring="neg_mean_squared_error")
print((foo["test_score"] < 0.0).all())
```

Which prints `True`. This shows that the return from `cross_validate` with `"neg_mean_squared_error"` must be the **negative** of the square error (because squaring a real number is non-negative). If you *negate* the function that you're minimizing, the minimization  transforms into a maximization. **Therefore, the code in the question is maximizing model misfit.**

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting example. Here is some R code for some **naive** analysis on Boston Housing data (predicting the median value MEDV):

```r
library(mlbench)
library(glmnet)
data("BostonHousing")

n = nrow(BostonHousing)
train_idx = sample(n, round(0.7*n))
train_data = BostonHousing[train_idx, ]
test_data = BostonHousing[-train_idx, ]
lmod = lm(medv ~ ., data = train_data)
mean(lmod$residuals^2) # training MSE for the linear model

r_col = ncol(train_data) # which column contains the response -- here it is the last column

lasso_mod = cv.glmnet(x = data.matrix(train_data[, -r_col]), y = train_data$medv, nfolds = 5)
lasso_mod
ridge_mod = cv.glmnet(x = data.matrix(train_data[, -r_col]), y = train_data$medv, nfolds = 5, alpha = 0)
ridge_mod

loss = function(x,xh) mean((x-xh)^2)

loss(predict(lmod, test_data[,-r_col]), test_data$medv)
loss(predict(lasso_mod, data.matrix(test_data[,-r_col])), test_data$medv)
loss(predict(ridge_mod, data.matrix(test_data[,-r_col])), test_data$medv)


plot(lasso_mod)
plot(ridge_mod)
```

The numbers for the test MSE of the linear model, the Lasso and the Ridge are 26.7, 33 and 32.2. The latter two are the default models selected by the `glment`. These numbers are quite variable since this is based on a single training/test split, however, the order seems to be roughly the same. At least the linear model always does better (in my limited set of runs).

Here are the regularization curves produced by the `glmnet` package:
For the Lasso:
[image]

For the Ridge:
[image]

They do suggest that the best regularization is essentially no regularization ($\lambda = 0$) which is consistent with the results.

Do you always have to get a better result with Lasso and/or ridge? No if $\lambda = 0$ is the best choice.

What can you do? Perhaps try to be more refined in what variables to include in the model and better take care of the categorical variables. The above analysis does it naively treating categorical variables as integers which is not that meaningful. In the end, there is no guarantee that Lasso or ridge do better than the linear model.

You can try some non-parametric regression models too. You can also do polynomial regression coupled with lasso to reduce the complexity.

PS. The training MSEs for the above setup are 20.8 for the linear model and the following for Lasso:

```r
Measure: Mean-Squared Error 

    Lambda Index Measure    SE Nonzero
min 0.0174    65   24.78 4.346      13
1se 0.9505    22   28.85 5.214       6
```

and for the following for ridge:

```r
Measure: Mean-Squared Error 

    Lambda Index Measure    SE Nonzero
min  0.671   100   22.91 2.166      13
1se  3.578    82   25.03 2.229      13
```

Comment: This is a good demonstration. In conducting these experiments, did you ever find that the lasso or ridge model selected by the procedure had a higher holdout MAE or holdout MSE compared to OLS? Can you use this demonstration to infer why OP discovered that the OLS models had lower holdout error than the lasso and ridge models?

Comment: If by hold out you mean the test MSE, yes, the selected Lasso and Ridge have higher test MSE relative to OLS. Even their training MSEs are higher. I have also added the training MSEs. OLS seems to have the smallest training and test MSEs.

Comment: In many cases in which the number of observations is comfortably larger (say by a factor of 10-20 or more) than the number of variables, variable selection and regularisation don't do any good. The idea that this is somehow mandatory is simply wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the details explanation. But, if i do hypertuning for Lasso then I should get the better score than the default params Lasso. But, I am getting better score for the default Lasso than the tuned Lasso. Could you tell me why I am getting this?

Comment: @Opps_0 because your code is **maximizing** model misfit, not minimizing.

Comment: But from this blog, "we are trying to find the set of parameters that minimizes the neg_mean_squared_error , or pick the point with the minimum mean squared error"  (https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-model-selection-and-hyperparameter-tuning-736158357dc4)

Comment: @Opps_0, it is hard to tell without knowing what the default lasso is in your case and whether you did the hyperparameter tuning correctly. Could it be that the default version is doing some sort of internal CV? You can do hyperparameter tuning by hand (i.e. by grid search) to see what is going on. When you rely on many packages for doing different tasks, there is also a chance that you are not using one of them correctly,

Comment: After tuned the Lasso and Ridge, I am using KFold for all LinReg for final training and testing, Lasso and Ridge. The default means, just use `LinearRegression()` from SkLearn